# Необходимо дописать код таким образом, чтобы появилась возможность завершать праздники - возможность снять галочку

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Вот как выглядит код:

```
    import { useReducer } from "react";

const initialHolidays = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Christmas",
    complete: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "8th March",
    complete: false,
  },
];

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "COMPLETE":
      return state.map((holiday) => {
        // Добавить здесь
        // Условие на сравнение по holiday.id
        // и вернуть новое состояние holiday, 
        // учесть complete
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

function Holidays() {
  const [holidays, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialHolidays);

  const handleComplete = (holiday) => {
    // В reducer передается такой объект:
    dispatch({ type: "COMPLETE", id: holiday.id });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {holidays.map((holiday) => (
        <div key={holiday.id}>
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={holiday.complete}
              onChange={() => handleComplete(holiday)}
            />
            {holiday.title}
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Holidays;
```

Comment: Можете пояснить, что именно должен делать экшн? Например, на массиве в initialHolidays какой должен быть результат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, нужен экшн, который меняет состояние текущего праздника? Если так, то вот вариант:

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'COMPLETE':
      return state.map((holiday) =>
        holiday.id === action.id
          ? {
              ...holiday,
              complete: !holiday.complete,
            }
          : holiday,
      );

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, именно это и требовалось